# Team Foundation Server script error in vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

[image]

i can't Go Online my project for checkin it's show error like this picture.

How to solve it's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Online requires IE9 or later. You appear to be using an unsupported browser.